# Can't to check my rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i typing `rails -v` in console, system returns me:

```
not find gem 'devise (>= 4.2.1, ~> 4.2) java' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.?

`bundle install` to install missing gems.?
```

of course `bundle install` does not help me, deletion gemfile.lock also does not help me.
How can i repair it ?

of course `bundle install` does not help me, deletion gemfile.lock also does not help me.
How can i repair it ?

my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'

gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'

gem 'devise'

group :development, :test do

  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri

end

group :development do

  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'

end


gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
   gem 'pg', '0.18.2'
   gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.3'
end
```

Comment: Can you provider more information. ? did you add the devise gem ?

Comment: i added to file Gemfile this gem 'devise', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.1'

Comment: just add `gem 'devise'` and run bundle

Comment: now: not find gem 'devise java'

Comment: can you provide the gem file ?

Comment: yes, edited done

Comment: Okay you need to define `gem devise ` at the bottom of file. after group production. try it

Comment: now: Could not find gem 'web-console (>= 3.3.0) java' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Comment: may be you changed the any lib file.